# Python store line by line in List from Text File

Tags: python

i have a text file like so and i would like to process it in python

**info.txt**

```
    firstname1
    surname1
    email@email.com1
    student1
 -------------------
    firstname2
    surname2
    email@email.com2
    student2
-----------------
```

i want to write a python code which iterares and stores each line in each indexs example: `[firstname,surname,email@email.com,student]` and ignore the `"-----"`

**python code**

```
 with open('log.txt') as f:
        lines = f.read().splitlines()
        x = x + 1

    for i in lines:
        print i
```

but i believe this is wrong i amm very new to python can some one please point me in the correct direction
i want the output to me somthing like so

**output**

```
index 1 :first name: firstname1
         Surname: surname1
         Email: email@email.com1
         Student student1

index 2 :first name: firstname2
         Surname: surname2
         Email: email@email.com2
         student: student2
```

Comment: Please be more specific about the output/result you want. Also, what is `x` supposed to do in your code?

Comment: updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it'd be better form to explain the general guidelines of how to do something like this, but for a simple task like this, the code speaks for itself, really...

I'd implement it like this.

```
from pprint import pprint  # For nicer formatting of the output.

# For the sake of a self-contained example,
# the data is inlined here.
#
# `f` could be replaced with `open('log.txt').

f = """
    firstname1
    surname1
    email@email.com1
    student1
-------------------
    firstname2
    surname2
    email@email.com2
    student2
-----------------
""".splitlines()

data = []
current = None
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()  # Remove leading and trailing spaces
    if not line:  # Ignore empty lines
        continue  # Skip the rest of this iteration.
    if line.startswith('-----'):  # New record.
        current = None  # Clear the `current` variable
        continue  # Skip the rest of the iteration
    if current is None:  # No current entry?
        # This can happen either after a ----- line, or
        # when we're dealing with the very first line of the file.

        current = []  # Create an empty list,
        data.append(current)  # and push it to the list of data.
    current.append(line)

pprint(data)
```

The output is a list of lists:

```
[['firstname1', 'surname1', 'email@email.com1', 'student1'],
 ['firstname2', 'surname2', 'email@email.com2', 'student2']]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that might be a bit more elegant. (As long as your file strictly keeps the format from your example, that is four lines of data followed by a dashed line.)

```
from itertools import izip # skip this line if you are using Python 3

with open('info.txt') as f:
    result = [{'first name': first.strip(), 'Surname': sur.strip(),
               'Email': mail.strip(), 'student': stud.strip()}
              for first, sur, mail, stud, _ in izip(*[f]*5)]
```

This gives you a list of dictionaries as follows:

```
[{'first name': 'firstname1', 'Surname': 'surname1', 'Email': 'email@email.com1', 'student': 'student1'}, {'first name': 'firstname2', 'Surname': 'surname2', 'Email': 'email@email.com2', 'student': 'student2'}]
```

Where your "index 1" corresponds to the first element of the list (i.e. `result[0]`), "index 2" corresponds to the second element of the list, and so on.

For example, you can get the surname of your `index == 2` with:

```
index = 2
result[index - 1]['Surname']
```

If you are really bothered that the index is shifted, you could built a dictionary from the result. Demo:

```
>>> result = dict(enumerate(result, 1))
>>> result
{1: {'first name': 'firstname1', 'Surname': 'surname1', 'Email': 'email@email.com1', 'student': 'student1'}, 2: {'first name': 'firstname2', 'Surname': 'surname2', 'Email': 'email@email.com2', 'student': 'student2'}}
>>>
>>> result[2]['Surname']
'surname2'
>>>
>>> for index, info in result.items():
...     print index, info['first name'], info['Surname'], info['Email'], info['student']
... 
1 firstname1 surname1 email@email.com1 student1
2 firstname2 surname2 email@email.com2 student2
```